# Calculate time between events SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write query which will calculate time difference between rows in but I fail horribly.

Problem is that events are not always one after another and if this is the case it should return NULL value or skip it completely.

Example table

| Time | ComputerName | RenderedDescription | EventDisplayNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-19 14:12:58.400 | COMP16 | The Event log service was started. | 6005 |
| 2022-05-19 13:52:46.360 | COMP16 | The Event log service was stopped. | 6006 |
| 2022-05-19 13:15:47.417 | COMP16 | The Event log service was started. | 6005 |
| 2022-05-08 08:26:11.777 | COMP16 | The Event log service was started. | 6005 |
| 2022-05-08 07:30:11.030 | COMP16 | The Event log service was stopped. | 6006 |
| 2022-05-01 08:22:37.553 | COMP16 | The Event log service was started. | 6005 |
| 2022-05-01 07:30:08.057 | COMP16 | The Event log service was stopped. | 6006 |
| 2022-04-24 08:20:55.190 | COMP16 | The Event log service was started. | 6005 |
| 2022-04-24 07:30:07.143 | COMP16 | The Event log service was stopped. | 6006 |

And result which I am trying to get

| ComputerName | Event Stopped | Event Started | DifferenceMinutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COMP16 | 2022-04-24 07:30:07.143 | 2022-04-24 08:20:55.190 | 50 |
| COMP16 | 2022-05-01 07:30:08.057 | 2022-05-01 08:22:37.553 | 52 |
| COMP16 | 2022-05-08 07:30:11.030 | 2022-05-08 08:26:11.777 | 56 |
| COMP16 | NULL | 2022-05-19 13:15:47.417 | NULL |
| COMP16 | 2022-05-19 13:52:46.360 | 2022-05-19 14:12:58.400 | 20 |

Comment: Use `LAG` and then filter to the start events? Assuming, of course, you can't have 2 starts or stops in a row.

Comment: @Larnu, thing is that it can happen to have 2 or more starts or stops in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on your sample data:

```
with Data as (
    select *,
        case when RenderedDescription like '%started%' then 'S'
             when RenderedDescription like '%stopped%' then 'E' end as Code,
        count(case when RenderedDescription like '%started%' then 1 end)
            over (partition by ComputerName order by "Time" desc) as Grp
    from EventLog
)
select
    ComputerName,
    max(case when Code = 'E' then "Time" end) as EventStopped,
    min(case when Code = 'S' then "Time" end) as EventStarted,
    datediff(second, 
        max(case when Code = 'E' then "Time" end),
        min(case when Code = 'S' then "Time" end)
    ) / 60 as DifferenceMinutes

from Data
group by ComputerName, Grp
order by ComputerName, EventStarted;
```

If you can both have consecutive starts and stops then try this instead:

```
with Data as (
    select *,
        case when RenderedDescription like '%started%' then 'S'
             when RenderedDescription like '%stopped%'  then 'E' end as Code,
        lag(
            case when RenderedDescription like '%started%' then 'S'
                 when RenderedDescription like '%stopped%'  then 'E' end
        ) over (partition by ComputerName order by "Time") as LastCode
    from EventLog
), Grouped as (
    select *,
        count(case when LastCode = 'E' and Code = 'S' then null else 1 end)
            over (partition by ComputerName order by "Time") as Grp
    from Data
)
select
    ComputerName,
    max(case when Code = 'E' then "Time" end) as EventStopped,
    min(case when Code = 'S' then "Time" end) as EventStarted,
    datediff(second, 
        max(case when Code = 'E' then "Time" end),
        min(case when Code = 'S' then "Time" end)
    ) / 60 as DifferenceMinutes
from Grouped
group by ComputerName, Grp
order by ComputerName, EventStarted;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7bd556c49cbca84d025bcd1eedc9771

Comment: Thank you @shawnt00. Yes it can be that there is no stop only some starts consecutive or other way around so I wanted to take out only those which have stop and start after and their difference exactly what you wrote. Thanks again